# Why do we see random delays in traffic between two Docker containers?

Tags: linux-networking, docker-swarm

I'm looking at a Docker swarm host, which is the only host in our Docker swarm cluster (no, not recommended).

Due to a [DNS issue in Moby](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30134#issuecomment-355782984) we've sent intra-container traffic via either the host's external IP (192.168.1.50) or via `docker_gwbridge` (172.18.0.1). This works as these requests will be DNAT'ed to 172.18.0.2 (which fronts a Docker container handling the VIP / load balancing functionality)

We see randomly that request duration between an nginx container and memcached container (two different containers) takes 1 second or more.

We see this by running [mc_conn_tester.pl](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/Timeouts) inside the nginx container.

- When traffic between the two containers go via 192.168.1.50, the mc_conn_tester.pl reports a lot of 1 sec requests when we use 192.168.1.50 also in the test. If we run mc_conn_tester.pl against 172.18.0.1 instead, we do not see any 1 sec requests.
- When traffic between the two containers go via 172.18.0.1, the mc_conn_tester.pl reports a lof of one 1 sec requests when we use 172.180.1 in the test. If we run mc_conn_tester.pl against 192.168.1.50 instead, we do not see any 1 sec requests.

What could cause this behaviour and give 1 sec (and up) delays, and how can we debug this further?

**Followup on** https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/36032

Comment: could you create an image and info for others to test this setup? I'd say before t/s further, be sure you're on a 4.x kernel, using 17.12 latest stable release, and don't use CPU-cycle limiting VM's like AWS T2.

Comment: @BretFisher we upgraded to 17.12 this morning, so we'll be keeping an eye. Running on Hyper-V and 4.x kernel. We discovered in the end that the ingress-sbox drops a lot of packets from the nginx, which memcached never gets.